# jquery .hide() and .show()

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

```
        $(".navItemWetten").click(function(){
            $(".navUnderItemWetten").hide();
        });

     <nav>
        <?php
            //Falls man eingeloggt ist
            if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
        ?>
            <a href="logout.php" ><button class="logOutBtn" type="button">Log Out</button></a>
            <h1><p>Backend</p></h1><br /> <br />
            <a><li class="navItemWetten" >Wetten</li></a>
            <a><li class="navUnderItemWetten" >Super League</li></a>
        <?php
            } else {
        ?>
            <h1><p>Backend</p></h1>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </nav>
```

I just want, that when i click on the class `navItemWetten` that the class `navUnderItemWetten` is hidden. I have included ajax

Comment: Okay, you already have. So?

Comment: what? don't tell me you have a valid markup.

Comment: Fix your markup, put your li elements inside of a ul tag and the anchors inside of the li tags, and if it still doesn't work use event delegation as demonstrated in @PraveenKumar 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this doesn't work on items that load via AJAX. You need to use delegation. To elaborate, elements that are generated or recreated by an ajax call will lose any events that are attached to them, unless they are [delegated](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$("body").on("click", ".navItemWetten", function(){
    $(".navUnderItemWetten").hide();
});
```

And remove the button that is inside of `<a>`. Also please do not nest `<p>` inside of `<hX>` tags.

**Solution**

1. The whole layout is wrong. The LI can be contained only inside `<ul>` and you should not put any block level elemenets inside `<a>` tag.
2. You must include the code inside document ready function.
3. You must use `.toggle()` instead of `.hide()` and `.show()`.

**Snippet**

```js
// You must include the code inside document ready function.
$(function () {
    $(".navItemWetten").click(function(){
        $(".navUnderItemWetten").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- The whole layout is wrong. The LI can be contained only inside <ul> and you should not put any block level elemenets inside <a> tag. -->
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="navItemWetten" ><a>Wetten</a></li>
        <li class="navUnderItemWetten" ><a>Super League</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't think there is any ajax.

Comment: I seriously wanna know who's the other one has the same question as @BuddhiAbeyratne...

Comment: @Jai *I have included ajax*.

Comment: @PascalHurni Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @PraveenKumar still finding it.  where is it?

Comment: To elaborate, elements that are generated or recreated by an ajax call will lose any events that are attached to them, unless they are [delegated](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). That is what `.on()` does in this context.

Comment: @Jai Read the question.

Comment: @PraveenKumar **no offence** i've read that but i am not able to find the ajax which is included. did you find that piece?

Comment: is there any error in your browser console? @PascalHurni

Comment: @Jai Even I can't find that. Having said that he uses AJAX, anyway this solution doesn't work it seems.

Comment: @PraveenKumar That's where i commented at the question post.

Comment: Your `<li>`s are nested inside anchors (`<a>`) instead of a `<ul>`, which might be causing your view to bug out and the click event to not be captured.